# contains function for String in presto Athena

Tags: mysql, contains, amazon-athena, presto, string-function

I have a table with `ORC` Serde in Athena. The table contains a string column named `greeting_message`. It can contain **null** values as well. I want to find how many rows in the table have a particular text as the pattern.

Let's say my sample data looks like below:

```
|greeting_message |
|-----------------|
|hello world      |
|What's up        |
|                 |
|hello Sam        |
|                 |
|hello Ram        |
|good morning, hello |
|                 |
|the above row has null |
| Good morning Sir |
```

Now for the above table, if we see there are a total of 10 rows. 7 of them are having not null values and 3 of them just has null/empty value.

**I want to know what percentage of rows contain a specific word.**

For example, consider the word `hello`. It is present in 4 rows, so the percentage of such rows is 4/10 which is 40 %.

Another example: the word `morning` is present in 2 messages. So the percentage of such rows is 2/10 which is 20 %.

**Note** that I am considering `null` also in the count of the denominator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of prestoDB (Amazon Athena engine) is different than MySQL. The following example is creating a temp table `WITH greetings AS` and then `SELECT` from that table:

```
WITH greetings AS
  (SELECT 'hello world' as greeting_message UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Whats up' UNION ALL
   SELECT '' UNION ALL
   SELECT 'hello Sam' UNION ALL
   SELECT '' UNION ALL
   SELECT 'hello Ram' UNION ALL
   SELECT 'good morning, hello' UNION ALL
   SELECT '' UNION ALL
   SELECT 'the above row has null' UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Good morning Sir')

 SELECT count_if(regexp_like(greeting_message, '.*hello.*')) / cast(COUNT(1) as real) AS hello_percentage, 
       count_if(regexp_like(greeting_message, '.*morning.*')) / cast(COUNT(1) as real) AS morning_percentage 
FROM greetings
```

will give the following results

| hello_percentage | morning_percentage |
| --- | --- |
| 0.4 | 0.2 |

The *regex_like* function can support many regex options including spaces (\s) and other string matching requirements.

Comment: Thanks, @Guy. This answer helps a lot.

Answer (score 5):

```sql
SELECT SUM(greeting_message LIKE '%hello%') / COUNT(*) AS hello_percentage, 
       SUM(greeting_message LIKE '%morning%') / COUNT(*) AS morning_percentage 
FROM tablename
```

Comment: Thanks, @Akina. How to select the message with spaces in between. For example, the message containing `Linear value=`. It is telling me that it has extraneous input. Notice the space between the word linear and value.

Comment: @AjayKrChoudhary o_O `greeting_message LIKE '%Linear value=%'`... any char except percent and underscore is treated as regular char, including space.

Comment: Getting this error now: Your query has the following error(s):
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:8: Unexpected parameters (boolean) for function sum. Expected: sum(double) , sum(real) , sum(bigint) , sum(decimal(p,s))

Comment: @AjayKrChoudhary This is **not** MySQL error message - refer to the user manual for your programming language, I cannot help you in this situation.